# Amazon EC2 instance with a specific EBS Volume Size Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sdk

I'm using the java SDK to spin up instances and it's working well.
On issue is that the volume is 8GB

```
RunInstancesRequest runInstancesRequest = new RunInstancesRequest();
runInstancesRequest.withImageId(AMI_ID).withInstanceType(INSTANCE_TYPE).withMinCount(1).withMaxCount(1)
    .withKeyName(KEY_NAME).withSecurityGroups(SECURITY_GROUP).withMonitoring(true);
RunInstancesResult runInstancesResult = ec2.runInstances(runInstancesRequest);
```

There doesn't seem to be anything in the `RunInstancesRequest` class but `withBlockDeviceMappings` seems to create a separate volume.
How do you specify the size of the volume?

Comment: hi David, have you got the solution for this ?

Comment: @Jugi I used BlockDeviceMapping class and set it's EbsBlockDevice, there you can set the volume size. Which needs to be added to a ArrayList<BlockDeviceMapping> which is then set in the run instance request.

Answer (score 1):

`com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.Volume` will help you.

Mehtod: setSize(Integer size)

[API Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/Volume.html#setSize-java.lang.Integer-)

Comment: Thanks but where is the Volume class passed to?